# What is the regex for this?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net, visual-c++

First of all I guess I will start by asking what are some good tools or references for building regex strings? I usually find them on the net, but I would love to learn them a little more.

Now on to my original question: what is the Regex to find a full string, or find a line that contains the string. The string is:

```
** Start of
```

Comment: what do you want 2 match exactly!Do you want to search for a string starting from **

Comment: No need to use regular expressions to match a simple string. Simply use the `string.Contains()` method.

Comment: @knittl OP's intention is to learn to build regular expressions. There's no better way than to start with simple things and this simple match is a perfect test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While very informative, none of the answers provide the correct regex for your specific problem. Here it is:

```
string regexPattern = @"^.*?\*{2} Start of.*?$";
```

Note that you will have to specify `multiline` option when searching for match.

You can see the results **[here](http://regexr.com?32373)**.

And here's the explanation of the pattern:

```
^.*?\*{2} Start of.*?$

Options: ^ and $ match at line breaks

Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) «^»
Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
    Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character “*” literally «\*{2}»
    Exactly 2 times «{2}»
Match the characters “ Start of” literally « Start of»
Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
    Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) «$»
```

Answer (score 6):

The regex you are looking for is: `\*\* Start of.*`

Because C# has its own escape characters you may want to put this in a verbatim string like `@"\*\* Start of.*"`.

The best tool for helping you build, learn and understand regular expressions is [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/).  It helps you see the meaning of your expressions as well as test them through an intuitive graphical UI.
[image: It helps you see the meaning of your expressions as well as test them through an intuitive graphical UI]

The most complete resource for information on regular expressions (across different languages) is http://www.regular-expressions.info/ .  If you are looking to learn about a specific Regular Expression implementation you might be better of reading the implementation-specific documentation/spec.  For .NET, a good starting place would be the [Regex documentation at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx)  You can also test .NET regular expressions quickly online with the free tool available at http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

I also would like to note that I agree with @ziesemer that using an `IndexOf` or `StartsWith` method is probably a better solution for such a simple pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're using the wrong tool for the job.  Regular expressions are best suited for finding patterns.  It seems you're only looking to do a simple search - use the proper API (e.g. `IndexOf`) for this.

Otherwise, you simply need to escape the asterisks - which are special characters in regular expressions - meaning "match 0 or more of":

```
\*\* Start of
```

Answer (score 0):

For learning regex you could check the [Regular Expression Basic Syntax Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) on [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info) and also additionally [A Gentle Introduction: The Basics](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm)

And regarding the string to find if you want only character from a to z then I think you should write as

```
^[a-zA-Z]$
```

This will take small and capital a to z characters.

### Update

```
^\*\* Start of(.*?)$
```

**Spliting Detail**

- `\*`, take asterisk into consideration
- `Start of`, compare exactly the this string
- `(.*?)`, take anything on that single line

  `^\*\* Start of(.*?)(([\n]*(.*?)){19})*$`

**Spliting Detail**

- `\*`, take asterisk into consideration
- `Start of`, compare exactly the this string
- `(.*?)(([\n]*(.*?)){19})*`, take anything but limit upto 19 lines